# How to refer a lib in different location in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the structure of our team code in python,

```
`tree -L 1 apps/sockstunnel/sockstunnel auto_tasks/FEXT_STACKER/`

apps/sockstunnel/sockstunnel
├── api.py
├── db.py
├── exceptions.py
├── flags.py
├── frame.py
├── __init__.py
├── libfix.py
├── notification.py
├── protocols.py
├── proxy_router.py
└── service.py
auto_tasks/FEXT_STACKER/
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── licenses
├── README
├── stacker.py
└── tmp
```

of which,

1. "apps" and "auto_tasks" are in the same dir.
2. "auto_tasks/FEXT_STACKER/stacker.py" is the project I am currently  working on, and it needs to refer to a call inside this "apps/sockstunnel/sockstunnel/protocols.py" file.

My question is, what I can do on "stacker.py" side, so that contents of this "protocols.py" can be referred ? I am using python3.9.

**Some Update**:

I have tried these 2 ways in my stacker.py:

A) :

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/../../apps/sockstunnel")
```

B)

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/absolute/path/to/this/<apps/sockstunnel>")
```

The 1st one fails, and the 2nd one works. But obviously, I would like to have the 1st option in my code. So what should I do.

Comment: did  you try  setting the PYTHONPATH environment variable ?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I did give a try by using PYTHONPATH. and it raise some other exception issue. Any alternative way I may try ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the working directory using os.chdir(path)